# $ and document are defined, but $(document) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4 which is working, including features which need javascript.

However, if I add

```
$(document).ready(function() {console.log("hi"))
```

to my HTML page I get the error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

I verified on the browser console that:

- $ is defined
- $("body") is defined
- document is defined

But $(document) is undefined.
What is wrong?

Comment: You are missing a `}`.

Comment: Did you check `$(document)` in the console?

Comment: Have you tried if `$(document)` works when you try it in browser console? It seems that you are executing the code in your application before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: $(document) does not work in the console.
Since $ does work I assume that jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to add `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` to your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

define this as the first script on your page.

Comment: I think it is not the problem because $ and $("body") are defined.

Comment: can you please share your code in your question please.